# The thread MultiplicationThreading cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

My goal here is to use multithreading programming to make a matrix multiplication application of two matrices. I am having an error in the Matrix.java class where I create a new thread called MultiplicationThreading. The console says it cannot resolve it to a type. This is the only error in my code and I am trying to figure out if there is a better way to write this line.

Here is my Matrix.java, where the problem is located at the new thread MultiplicationThreading.

```
package src;

public class Matrix {
public static int NUM_THREADS = 10;
public static void main(String args[]) 
{

int i; // row
int j; // column
int A[][] = { { 1, 4 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 6 } };
int B[][] = { { 8, 7, 6 }, { 5, 4, 3 } };
int C[][] = new int[3][3];
Thread[] matrixWorker = new Thread[NUM_THREADS];
/**
* Creates threads in order to multiply
*/
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //rows
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //columns
matrixWorker[i] = new Thread(new MultiplicationThreading(i, j, A, B,C)); //ERROR IS HERE
matrixWorker[i].start();
matrixWorker[i].join();
} 
}
/**
* Prints out Matrix C
*/
System.out.println("Matrix: ");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
System.out.print(C[i][j] + ", ");
}
System.out.print("\n");
  }
 }
}
```

If it helps, this is my other class, called MultipleThread.java

```
package src;

public class MultipleThread implements Runnable {
private int i; // row
private int j; // column
private int A[][];
private int B[][];
private int C[][];
public MultipleThread(int row, int col, int A[][], int B[][], int
C[][]) {
this.i = row;
this.j = col;
this.A = A;
this.B = B;
this.C = C;
}
/**
* Calculates matrix product in C[row][column]
*/
public void run() {
for (int t = 0; t < B.length; t++) {
C[i][j] += (A[i][t]) * (B[t][j]);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your class name is MultipleThread isn't it? Then why are you using MultiplicationThreading?

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0):

you have put the name of class incorrectly.

> matrixWorker[i] = new Thread(new MultipleThread(i, j, A, B,C));
>   //ERROR IS HERE